# inequality with min on both sides

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $r\in[0,1]$ and $z\in\mathbb C,\mathrm{Im}z> 0.$ I am struggling to prove the following inequality:
$$\frac{2(1+|z|)r}{\sqrt{|z^2-4|}}\wedge\sqrt{(1+|z|)r}\leq3\left(\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{|z^2-4|}}\right)r\right]\wedge\sqrt{r}\right),$$
where $x\wedge y=\min(x,y).$ This is trivial for $r=0.$
First I supposed that $r>0$ and
$$\frac{2(1+|z|)r}{\sqrt{|z^2-4|}}\leq\sqrt{(1+|z|)r},$$
which implies that
$$\sqrt{r}\leq\frac{\sqrt{|z^2-4|}}{2\sqrt{(1+|z|)}},$$
but I was unable to get something non-trivial out of this.

Comment: What happens when $z=2$?

Comment: It holds since $\sqrt{3r}\leq 3 sqrt{r}$

Comment: so you consider the devision by zero as infinity?

Comment: The limit at 2 is +infinity and there is a minimum anyway, so both sides are well defined at 2

Comment: First of all, You can simplify the inequality. pay attension that if $a,b,c\ge0$ then $a \min{(b,c)}=\min{(ab,ac)}$. Now, since $\sqrt{|z^2-4|}\ge0$ we can multiply/divide the inequality with this term and the result won't change. therefore the inequality is the same as:

$2(1+|z|)r
\wedge
\sqrt{(1+|z|)r}\cdot\sqrt{|z^2-4|}
\leq
3\left(\left(\sqrt{|z^2-4|}+1\right)r
\wedge
\sqrt{|z^2-4|}\cdot\sqrt{r}\right)$

$2r(1+|z|)
\wedge
\sqrt{(1+|z|)}\cdot\sqrt{r|z^2-4|}
\leq
3r\left(\sqrt{|z^2-4|}+1\right)
\wedge
3\sqrt{r|z^2-4|}$

Comment: Yes, and then? I don't see what it brings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true.

For $r=0.01,z=2+0.1i$, we have
$$|z^2-4|=|-0.01+0.4i|=\sqrt{0.1601},\quad |z|=\sqrt{4.01}$$
$$\frac{2(1+|z|)r}{\sqrt{|z^2-4|}}=\frac{2(1+\sqrt{4.01})0.01}{\sqrt{\sqrt{0.1601}}}\approx 0.095$$

$$\sqrt{(1+|z|)r}=\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{4.01})0.01}\approx 0.173$$

$$3\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{|z^2-4|}}\right)r\right]=3\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{0.1601}}}\right)0.01\right]\approx 0.077$$

$$3\sqrt{r}=3\sqrt{0.01}=0.3$$

Therefore, the following inequality does not hold :
$$\frac{2(1+|z|)r}{\sqrt{|z^2-4|}}\wedge\sqrt{(1+|z|)r}\leq 3\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{|z^2-4|}}\right)r\right]\wedge 3\sqrt{r}$$